# Use of abstract Decorator class in Decorator pattern

Tags: c#, design-patterns

In Decorator design pattern we have an ItemClass (p.e. Coffee), then an AbstractDecorator (p.e. CoffeeDecorator) that contains a reference to Coffee, and ConcreteDecorators (such as milk). My question is, why do we need AbstractDecorator class, why don't Concrete Decorators inherit directly from Coffee class? Or why don't we have an interface that contains ItemClass property, if we already want to ensure that ConcreteDecorators have a reference to ItemClass? Bu using this AbstractDecorator we are just disabling an option that our ConcreteDecorators inherit some other class. Thanks, in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use abstract classes to remove duplication from concrete classes. In decorator pattern you have duplication of storing decorated object instance and passing calls to it. If you will not move this logic to base (abstract) decorator, then you will need to implement this in every concrete decorator.

---

Consider following beverage interface:

```
public interface IBeverage
{
    decimal Price { get; }
    string Description { get; }
}
```

which is implemented by coffee:

```
public class Coffee : IBeverage
{
    public decimal Price
    {
        get { return 3.5M; }
    }

    public string Description
    {
        get { return "Coffee"; }
    }
}
```

Now you want to create first decorator for coffee. You don't need to create abstract decorator at this moment. Let our milk bee free of charge. Just write simplest code you will need:

```
public class Milk : IBeverage
{
    private readonly IBeverage _beverage;

    public Milk(IBeverage beverage)
    {
        _beverage = beverage;
    }

    public decimal Price
    {
        get { return _beverage.Price; } // price not changed
    }

    public string Description
    {
        get { return _beverage.Description + " with milk"; }
    }
}
```

Now you need another decorator. Let it be cream:

```
public class Cream : IBeverage
{
    private readonly IBeverage _beverage;

    public Cream(IBeverage beverage)
    {
        _beverage = beverage;
    }

    public decimal Price
    {
        get { return _beverage.Price + 2M; }
    }

    public string Description
    {
        get { return _beverage.Description + " with cream"; }
    }
}
```

You can see duplicated code. So, it's time to refactoring. Let's move duplicated code to base abstract decorator class, which responsibility will be holding reference to decorated beverage and passing calls to it:

```
public abstract class BeverageDecorator : IBeverage
{
    private readonly IBeverage _beverage;

    public BeverageDecorator(IBeverage beverage)
    {
        _beverage = beverage;
    }

    public virtual decimal Price
    {
        get { return _beverage.Price; }
    }

    public virtual string Description
    {
        get { return _beverage.Description; }
    }
}
```

Now you can override only those calls which behavior changed by your decorator. Milk decorator will look like:

```
public class Milk : BeverageDecorator
{
    public Milk(IBeverage beverage)
        : base(beverage)
    {
    }

    public override string Description
    {
        get
        {
            return base.Description + " with milk";
        }
    }
}
```

Much cleaner, yes? That's why we use base decorator.

Comment: Ok, I agree. But isn't this a small price to pay, if you now have the luxury that your concrete decorator can implement some other class if needed? I'm still trying to get this pattern right, so I'm perhaps missing something?

Comment: Ok, now while looking at your code I realized that there is more benefit than just setting a reference to an object to be decorated... This way you encapsulate all the behavior that is same for your concrete decorators. But still, there's a voice in my head saying that it would be nice if you could make that concrete decorators open for implementation... :)

Comment: @breakpoint sorry, didn't get the problem. Duplication is always evil, so you need to avoid it. You are not forced to inherit ALL decorators from abstract decorator. If one of concrete decorators should implement some other class, then inherit it from that other class and implement IBeverage directly. BTW it's very strange requirement, to inherit from some other class. Consider to use composition instead of inheritance in this case.

Comment: Oh great, good point, that's the answer I was looking for... :) Thanks! One more question, what do you think about having an interface instead, in some cases, that just has a property that is a reference to IBeverage? In that way you would be able to achive that your concrete decorators have a reference needed, while in the same time they can implement some other class... BTW, thanks for mentioning that it is a rare case that such thing is neaded.

Comment: @breakpoint can you describe what an interface with IBeverage property will look like? Can't get your idea here

Comment: Well something like:
public interface IDecorator
{
IBeverage beverage { get; set; }
}
I haven't really used interfaces for such a thing, but I think it is possible to do a thing like that, just I don't know does it make sense?

Comment: @breakpoint main idea of this pattern is that decorator should BE the beverage (client actually does not know whether it have decorated beverage or not), it should not simply contain beverage. Also using of decorator interface does not remove any duplication - you still will need to implement decorated objects storage in every concrete decorator

Comment: I got the idea, but I lost the point in some moment... Thank you for your time, I've got your point. :)